# Display a gray scale image from a matrix in Java

Tags: java, image-processing, monochrome

I'm trying to read a file where a have a Matrix that represent an image monochrome,with **BufferedImage**  in JAVA like that

```
    final BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)img.getGraphics();
    ... /*reading from file*/ 
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.mac");
         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);
         // buffer for efficiency
         Reader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        int r;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        while ((r = buffer.read()) != -1) {
             g.setColor(new Color(?,?,?)); 
             g.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
             i++;
             if(i==WIDTH){
                 j++;
                 i=0;
             }
       }
    }
```

the problem is what i will set the color in this line `g.setColor(new Color(?,?,?));` that a get in `r` variable that represent the gray scale level in the matrix.

Comment: How does a character (not a byte) represent a grayscale level?  What is the value of `encoding`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set the color parameters, red, green and blue, to the same values to archive a grey color. The `Color` constructor accepts RGB values between [0, 255], so you will have to scale your r values to match the [0, 255] scale:

```
int grey = r/rMax * 255 //Gives you a grey value between [0, 255];
```

`rMax` being the biggest r value in your file.

Then set your color to

```
g.setColor(new Color(grey, grey, grey));
```

To make the whole thing more efficient, I would suggest creating an array of grey colors first to avoid creating a lot of duplicate `Color` objects:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[256];

for (int i = 0; i <=255; i++) {
    colors[i] = new Color(i, i, i);
}
```

and then set the `Color` in your loop to

```
g.setColor(colors[grey]);
```